# Como consultar en dos tablas PostgreSQL usando LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-9

Buen día tengas todos
Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a dos tablas en postgreSQL de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    product."pName",
    product."pCharacteristics",
    product.item_type,  
    product."basePrice",
    warehouse_product.warehouse,
    warehouse_product.stock,
    warehouse_product."minimumStock" 
FROM
    product
    LEFT JOIN warehouse_product ON product."pId" = warehouse_product.product 
WHERE
    product."pStatus" = 1   
ORDER BY
    product."pId" DESC
```

esto me trae la siguiente información
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es que cuando se insertan los productos que son servicios o kits  estos no se almacenan en la tabla relacionada warehouse_product y al hacer la consulta con el LEFT JOIN me trae estos productos con las columnas warehouse, stock, etc en null hasta hay estoy bien..
pero lo que quiero es poder por ejemplo consultar por la warehouse 3  pero que tambien me traiga los datos que llegan en null por el uso del left join.
de antemano muchas gracias.
Nota: esto lo quiero replicar en Laravel 9

Comment: Hola. Tendrías que agregar al `WHERE` las condiciones las columnas cuyos nulos quieres. Quedaría así más o menos: `WHERE product."pStatus" = 1   AND warehouse_product.warehouse IS NULL AND warehouse_product.stock IS NULL` Lo que dices del valor `3` no se entiende, ¿es un ID? ¿es un `pStatus`? Si quieres el `3` lo incluyes, sea en un `JOIN`, sea en el `WHERE`, dependiendo lo que sea, cosa que explicas con claridad.